# Spring set java.io.File property use java.lang.String bean

Tags: java, spring

I found a strange thing while learning Spring tech.

I inject a `java.lang.String` type bean into a bean property which type is `java.io.File`, but the program still runs normally.

I want to know

1. What happened internally?
2. Is it a valid usage or a trick?

Here is the spring configuration file `stringtofile.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="file_str"
          class="java.lang.String"
          c:_="C:\tmp\test.hi"/>

    <bean id="file"
          class="stringtofile.FileWrapper"
          p:file-ref="file_str"/>
</beans>
```

Here is my test classes.

```
package stringtofile;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.io.File;

public class FileWrapper {
    File file;

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public FileWrapper setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("stringtofile.xml");
        FileWrapper fileWrapper =
                (FileWrapper) ctx.getBean("file");
        System.out.println(fileWrapper.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by the PropertyEditors in your case the [FileEditor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/FileEditor.html)

Check the documentation here for more details: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Will this work with AnnotationConfigApplicationContext? Look at my code in my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43213385/3213514)